# Specify location of index files in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, spring, hibernate-search

hi guys
i am using hibernate search
and i want to specify the location for index files
right now i am indexing inside the project 
by the following:

```
@Indexed(index="indexes/myDomainClass")
```

but i was wondering how to specify the index to a location outside the app
i tried something like

```
@Indexed(index="/home/indexes/myDomainClass")
```

but it didn't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the `hibernate.search.default.indexBase` property (in persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml) to specify the base directory for the indices.

When using `AnnotationSessionFactoryB­ean` (or any session factory bean), you can set various properties via:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <util:properties>
          <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">value</prop>
    </util:properties>
</property>
```

(You'll need the util: namespace)

> xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

and in the schema locations:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd

Comment: but i don't use neither persistence.xml nor hibernate.cfg.xml, i am configuring my domain classes with hibernate annotations.

Comment: @sword101 then set that property programatically where you configure your session factory

Comment: i am setting my session factory like the following <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> when i tried to add the hibernate.search.default.indexBase property inside it, it didn't work, can you please guide me where to put this property then ?

Comment: i saw it, thanks, i used the property as you wrote with the namespases but i get the exception : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "util" for element "util:properties" is not bound

Comment: @sword101 as I noted, you have to add the namespace.

Comment: i added it in xsi:schemaLocation property

Comment: well, you also need to add the namespace, like all the rest. I didn't paste it, because I thought it was implied